# Do you smelt ore?

Tags: word-usage

Or do you smelt metal FROM ore?

I can’t tell which one (or both) is correct. I looked up the definition but I’m still not 100% sure.

Comment: It’s the ore that’s smelted. You smelt ore to produce metal. Like you bake dough to produce a cake. That said, you can “bake a cake”, right? And it’s not a cake that you put in the oven, it’s a cake you take out of the oven after the baking.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best forum for this question. Surely someone involving smelting and ore-related things would be more familiar than a group focused on EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples in the [Lexico entry for 'smelt'](https://www.lexico.com/definition/smelt) it is clear that 'smelt' is used for the process of extracting metal from ore using heat and that it is possible both to say that the *ore* is smelted and that the *metal* is smelted. However none of the examples suggests that the metal is 'smelted from' the ore. This accords with my own experience of the use of the word.

This fits with Dan Bron's explanation in his comment above where he compares the use of 'smelt' to the use of 'bake' in which one can both 'bake dough' to produce a cake and 'bake a cake'. In neither of those cases can you say that you have 'baked a cake *from* the dough'.